# Laravel: user defined object name in Join Query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a successfully returning join query written in Laravel. I am now trying to add an object name to the returned value as if it is returned from a table.

Laravel Query

```
$post = DB::table('follow')
    ->join('posts', 'follow.user2', '=', 'posts.userid')
    ->where('follow.user1',Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('follow.user2','!=',Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('posts.created_at','>',$update)
    ->select('posts.created_at', 'posts.userid')
    ->orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

The above query return the following

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
  object(stdClass)[208]
    public 'created_at' => int 1418466963
    public 'userid' => int 5
```

What I want to achieve is the following output

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
  object(stdClass)[208]
    public 'created_at' => int 1418466963
    public 'userid' => int 5
    public 'oType' => string 'post'  //This is user defined.
```

What I tried is (Obviously wrong but just a hint of what am I trying)

```
$post = DB::table('follow')
    ->join('posts', 'follow.user2', '=', 'posts.userid')
    ->where('follow.user1',Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('follow.user2','!=',Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('posts.created_at','>',$update)
    ->select('posts.created_at', 'posts.userid', 'oType as post') //Compare this line with 1st query
    ->orderBy('posts.created_at','desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a DB::raw().

```
->select('posts.created_at', 'posts.userid', DB::raw('\'post\' as oType'))
```

Comment: Laravel throws error

`syntax error, unexpected ':'` at `DB:raw('\'post\' as oType')`

Comment: Sorry, it should be DB::raw, not DB:raw. Corrected answer.